# Java Thread: wait, notifyAll and synchronized keywords not working as expected

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

***Current Status:** (Oct 10,2013): Solved.*

**Problem:**
I was studying the threads and decided to implement some assignment randomly.
So Google one and found this [assignment](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~als/cmsc330-f99/projects/assign7.html)

**Description** (Eliminating the game logic, main aim is to focus on the threads)
I have four players sitting in a circle, Cards have been divided between them. They will shuffle the their deck of cards (This task is for simplicity, obviously game logic is different), once all are done with their cards they can raise hands that they are done and then all can repeat the process, In technical terms threads will wait for others to finish and then whoever reaching or finishing last can notify others to continue...

**My code status:**

1. Different threads are entering in synchronized block at same time.
2. Once a thread completes his work, it should increment the count variable and count=4 current thread should notify the 3 other waiting for, ultimately I want to achieve happens-before relationship.

**Main Class:**

```
   public class RunGame implements Runnable{

    volatile int count=0;
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
    public static void main(String arg[]){

    RunGame obj= new RunGame();

    Player p1= new Player("Player 1");
    Player p2= new Player("Player 2");
    Player p3= new Player("Player 3");
    Player p4= new Player("Player 4");

    Runnable r1 = new ThreadRun(p1,obj);
    Runnable r2 = new ThreadRun(p2,obj);
    Runnable r3 = new ThreadRun(p3,obj);
    Runnable r4 = new ThreadRun(p4,obj);

    Thread t1 = new Thread(r1,"Player 1");
    Thread t2 = new Thread(r2,"Player 2");
    Thread t3 = new Thread(r3,"Player 3");
    Thread t4 = new Thread(r4,"Player 4");


    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
    t4.start();
    }
    }
```

**Model:**

```
  public class Player {
    private String player;

    public Player(String name) {
        this.player=name;
    }

    //getter and setter
}
```

**Business Class:**

```
    public class PlayerRun implements Runnable{

        Player player;

    RunGame mainObj;
    public PlayerRun(Player player,RunGame main) {
        this.player=player;
        this.mainObj=main;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true){
        synchronized (mainObj) {
            int count=mainObj.getCount();
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"...."+count);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mainObj.setCount(++count);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Done...."+count);
        }

        synchronized (mainObj) {
            try {
                if(mainObj.getCount()<=3)
                    mainObj.wait();//current thread will wait till it is awaken by notify.
                else if(mainObj.getCount()>3){
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is last one to enter and awake all");
                    mainObj.setCount(0);
                    mainObj.notifyAll();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"==============================");

        }
    }}
```

**Output:**

```
    Player 1....0
Player 1 Done....1
Player 4....1
Player 4 Done....2
Player 3....2
Player 3 Done....3
Player 2....3
Player 2 Done....4
Player 2 is last one to enter and awake all
Player 2==============================
Player 2....0
Player 3==============================
Player 4==============================
Player 2 Done....1
Player 1==============================
Player 4....1
Player 4 Done....2
Player 3....2
Player 3 Done....3
Player 1....3
Player 1 Done....4
Player 1 is last one to enter and awake all
Player 1==============================
Player 3==============================
Player 1....0
Player 1 Done....1
Player 4==============================
Player 3....1
Player 2==============================
Player 3 Done....2
Player 2....2
Player 2 Done....3
Player 4....3
Player 4 Done....4
Player 4 is last one to enter and awake all
Player 4==============================
Player 4....0
Player 3==============================
Player 2==============================
Player 4 Done....1
Player 1==============================
Player 2....1
Player 2 Done....2
Player 3....2
Player 3 Done....3
Player 1....3
Player 1 Done....4
Player 1 is last one to enter and awake all
Player 1==============================
Player 3==============================
Player 1....0
Player 1 Done....1
Player 2==============================
Player 4==============================
Player 3....1
Player 3 Done....2
Player 4....2
Player 4 Done....3
Player 2....3
Player 2 Done....4
Player 2 is last one to enter and awake all
Player 2==============================
Player 3==============================
Player 2....0
Player 1==============================
Player 4==============================
Player 2 Done....1
Player 4....1
Player 4 Done....2
Player 1....2
Player 1 Done....3
Player 3....3
Player 3 Done....4
Player 3 is last one to enter and awake all
Player 3==============================
Player 3....0
Player 1==============================
Player 3 Done....1
Player 4==============================
Player 1....1
Player 2==============================
Player 1 Done....2
Player 2....2
Player 2 Done....3
Player 4....3
Player 4 Done....4
Player 4 is last one to enter and awake all
Player 4==============================
Player 2==============================
Player 3==============================
Player 1==============================
Player 4....0
Player 4 Done....1
Player 1....1
Player 1 Done....2
Player 3....2
Player 3 Done....3
Player 2....3
Player 2 Done....4
Player 2 is last one to enter and awake all
```

Comment: a little confusion: suppose `ThreadRun 1` checks the current value of `count` and if it finds its value < 4 , it will update the value of `count` by 1. and then it will wait until the value of `count` becomes 4. Is this what you want?

Comment: No, it does not depend on the value of count, Actually Every thread will update the count on its turn, so after count 3 it will become 3, when 4th thread would enters it will increment it to 4 and notify all others to repeat the process.

Comment: So every thread will update the count on its turn and will go into `wait`, and when the 4th thread updates `count` it will notify others to wakeup.. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Actually Every thread will update the count on its turn, so after count 3 it will become 3, when 4th thread would enters it will increment it to 4 and notify all others to repeat the process.

The above statement is copied from your `comment`. And I think this changes the requirement that was there initially, as now you want to repeat the process all over again. For this, you need to replace the `increaseCount` method with two methods, one to make the threads wait if the `count < 4` and the other is to notify the waiting threads when the count becomes 4:

```
   //threads will increment the value of count by 1 and will wait if its value is
   //less than 4.
   public synchronized void increaseCount() throws InterruptedException {
        count++;
        if (count < 4) {
            wait();
        }
    }

    //4th thread will come inside this method, it will set the count value to 0
    //and will notify other threads
    public synchronized void releaseCount() throws InterruptedException {
        if (count >= 3) {
            count = 0;
            notifyAll();
        }

    }
```

And change the `PlayerRun` as this:

```
public class PlayerRun implements Runnable{
    RunGame runGame;
    ...
    public PlayerRun(Player player, RunGame runGame) {
        this.player = player;
        this.runGame = runGame; 
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public void run() {
    while (true) {
    // DO YOUR WORK
    runGame.releaseCount();
    runGame.increaseCount();
    }
    }
}
```

You don't need to use `synchronized` keyword inside the `run` method of `PlayerRun`. The  `synchronized` keyword is used to coordinate access to shared variables. You have your shared variable `count` in `RunGame`, to which you can provide synchronized access by using `synchronized` keyword on `increaseCount` and `relaesCount`.

Comment: Thanks Debojit, My question is still the same , why do my thread stops after certain iterations, no doubt your code is working great :)

Answer (score 1):

Your synchronize block takes separate lock for each player so locking is bound to fail.
See this:

```
synchronized (this) {

                try {

                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" work in progress..."+count);
                for(int i =0;i<=3;i++){
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                count++;
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" work Done..."+count);
```

} 
All the players should take lock on same object.

So you can create a common lock for all players and pass it down to PlayerRun to resolve this issue.

EDIT:

As per below comments user requirements is

> " If I understand it correctly he wants the players to do their work
>   (simultaneously) then everyone who's finished waits until the last one
>   is done with his work and they begin again."

This adds a completely new dimension tot he question. The approach taken of synchronized block is incorrect in this case as it will mean mutually exclusive approach. 
You should use `CyclicBarrier` , a single barrier for all threads and you can achieve this.

Comment: can you give me a hint.

Comment: @Lokesh But if you use a common lock there (on the work in progress) there will only be one player doing work at a time right...? Which kinda defeats the whole purpose.

Comment: @Alowaniak: Out of all multiple players users wants only one user be able to act on PlayerRun at a time, so you need common lock. Also logically speaking if user wants all players to play simultaneously then why do you need synchronize?

Comment: @Lokesh If I understand it correctly he wants the players to do their work (simultaneously) then everyone who's finished waits until the last one is done with his work and they begin again.

Comment: you got me right Alowaniak. Can you please point me in right direction and correct my code. Thanks

Comment: I see that problem is with count variable, which have different value at same time with in different thread stacks.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Different threads are entering in synchronized block at same time.

The synchronization mechanism is used to have coordinated access to shared variables in a multi threaded environment. Whenever more than one thread accesses a given state variable, and one of them must write to it, they all must coordinate their access to it using synchronization.

You are using `synchronized(this)` in the `run` method of the `PlayerRun` class, which says that only one `thread of execution` can execute this block of code at any given point in time. As you have created 4 `PlayerRun` instances and started them to run independently of each other, so they are entering their own `synchronized` blocks at the same time.

Again you have defined your `count` variable as static:

```
static volatile int count=0;
```

you need to use the runtime class of `PlayerRun` as the monitor, because it is not tied to any specific instance of `PlayerRun`. So the changes of the `count` variable should be synchronized on `PlayerRun.class`:

```
synchronized(PlayerRun.class)
{  
   count++;  
}
```

> Once a thread completes his work, it should increment the count variable and count=4 current thread should notify the 3 other waiting for, ultimately I want to achieve happens-before relationship.

The methods `wait, notify and notifyAll` gives a group of threads a way to wait for a specific condition to become true (these all are instance methods).  When you use `wait` on some object, it means the current thread of execution will wait for some condition to become true for this object. Whereas `notify` and `notifyAll` are used to notify other threads waiting on the same object. These set of methods are used when multiple threads are working with the same object and the way you have written your code is different from this approach.

My suggestion is to use one shared `counter` among all the threads. This you can achieve by defining a `count` variable in the `RunGame` class and pass an instance of this to `PlayerRun` runnables:

```
public class RunGame implements Runnable{

private int count=0;
...
public synchronized void increaseCount() throws InterruptedException {
      count++;
}
....
@Override
public void run() {
Runnable r1 = new PlayerRun(player1, this);
...
}
}
```

You can change the `PlayerRun` as this:

```
public class PlayerRun implements Runnable{
    RunGame runGame;
    ...
    public PlayerRun(Player player, RunGame runGame) {
        this.player = player;
        this.runGame = runGame; 
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public void run() {
    // DO YOUR WORK
    runGame.increaseCount();
    }
}
```